# Identity Server with EF not storing tokens to database

Tags: identityserver4

I have setup Identity Server using EF. How do I configure or in code setup the server to store the token in the database. When the cleanup process runs, it consistently logs 0 tokens available for cleanup.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, CustomSessionValidator>()
                    .AddTransient<IAuthRepository, CustomAuthRepository>();

services.AddIdentityServer()

                .AddSigningCredential(certificates[0])
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
                });
            services.AddDbContext<CustomApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

---

Client config. extracting from DB and displaying in code for completeness.

```
       new Client
            {
                ClientId = "",
                AllowedGrantTypes =
                {
                    GrantType.Hybrid,
                    GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                },

                ClientSecrets = 
                {
                    new Secret("".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "scope1",
                    "offline_access" },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
                AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 3600,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600
```

### },

Update: Thanks to tips. The documentation does not state that only the refresh token is stored. I was expecting the access token to be stored. Once configured the refresh token to the correct expiration time, the cleanup process started working.

Thanks
Greg

Comment: Please add your startup configuration. Not all tokens are stored in the database.

Comment: @aaronR thanks for the offer to help. I edited my question to include the config.

Comment: What types of Clients do you have configured?

Comment: @aaronR added client config. thanks for the help.

Comment: thanks @aaronR your tip about not token is stored helped me figure out that I had the refresh token configured wrong.